# Change color to TIF file with GDAL‏

Tags: python, tiff, gdal

I have a tif file named ndvi.tif that contains values between -1 and 1. The file is with one band.
In addition, I have a file ndvi.vrt which I am trying to edit.

My goal is to change the color of the image according to green-orange color values. Currently the picture is black and white.

I run the command:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Float32 C:\Users\oze\test.vrt C:\Users\oze\modified_palette.tif -scale -1 1
```

The resulting output is between 69-241 and the colors are still in black and white rather than green-orange as I expected.

This is the ndvi.vrt file:

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="1271" rasterYSize="3179">
  <SRS>PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 36N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",33],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32636"]]</SRS>
  <GeoTransform>  7.3790000000000000e+05,  1.0000000000000000e+01,  0.0000000000000000e+00,  3.6828200000000000e+06,  0.0000000000000000e+00, -1.0000000000000000e+01</GeoTransform>
  <Metadata>
    <MDI key="AREA_OR_POINT">Area</MDI>
  </Metadata>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Float32" band="1">
<ColorInterp>Green</ColorInterp>

    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">C:\Users\oze\test.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="1271" RasterYSize="3179" DataType="Float32" BlockXSize="1271" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="1271" ySize="3179" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="1271" ySize="3179" />
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

That's how it looks before everything:

[image: Image 1]

This is how it looks after the command is run:

[image: Image 2]

It's important to me that the colors look like this:

[image: Image 3]

These are the values before:

[image: Image 4]

These are the values after:

[image: Image 5]

That's what it's important for me to see:

[image: Image 6]

Comment: The raster you have is single band.  Some TIF file has three band or more, (e.g. true color satellite image) , and in that case tiff itself has  color.  It is typically visualization software's task to set color to the value of tif.  what visualization software are you using?  You have to use graduated scale or something in your vis software.  Alternatively, you can come up with (1) convert tif values to integer and use color mapped tiff or (2) convert tif into three band of RGB of color you picked.  but in these case original data is modified

Comment: First of all thank you for the explanation. Currently I show the files in the arcmap software but I want to view them in the browser. It is important for me to preserve the original values ​​and not to change them. It is also important to me that it be displayed in one band rather and no RGB. Is there another way to do this? Thank you

Comment: I still think that using integer values between 0-255 and add color map is most straight forward way.  I did something similar for my VCF (vegetation continuous field) data, although I used gdal-python, as i needed to perform other processing whihc was easier in python than stand-alone gdal tools.  You'd start with this wiki page https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQRaster#Howtocreateormodifyanimagecolortable  .  you'd also search web with keywords like colormap, geotif, gdal, etc.  gis.stackexchange.org is another nice forum for this kind of things.